# Java OPENCV Template Matching gives wrong coordinates?

Tags: java, opencv, coordinates, template-matching

so basically I am using Opencv Template Matching and it finds the correct match in the mainimage but the given coords of the match are wrong.

mainimage

[image: mainimage]

subimage

[image: subimage]

result

[image: result]

As you can see in the third picture, the algorithm found the right match. Also i wrote a print x, y to see the coords of the match and this gives me the following coords: 330, 1006. The value of x is right but the value of y is not right? how is this possible?

Code of the template matching method:

```
public void FindImageInFOE() {
    System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
    Mat source = null;
    Mat template = null;
    String filePath = "C:\\Users\\Gerrit\\Desktop\\";
    //Load image file
    source = Imgcodecs.imread(filePath + "jpgbeeld.jpg");
    template = Imgcodecs.imread(filePath + "jpghelpen.jpg");

    Mat outputImage = new Mat();
    int machMethod = Imgproc.TM_CCOEFF;
    //Template matching method
    Imgproc.matchTemplate(source, template, outputImage, machMethod);

    Core.MinMaxLocResult mmr = Core.minMaxLoc(outputImage);
    Point matchLoc = mmr.maxLoc;
    //Draw rectangle on result image
    Imgproc.rectangle(source, matchLoc, new Point(matchLoc.x + template.cols(),
            matchLoc.y + template.rows()), new Scalar(255, 255, 255));

    x = matchLoc.x;
    y = matchLoc.y;

    Imgcodecs.imwrite(filePath + "succes.png", source);
    System.out.println("Complated.");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Y coordinate is correct, it's counted from the top of the screen.

Top left is (0,0), bottom right is (1920,1080) on fullHD

Comment: Well something is going wrong in that case, because I am using util.java.robot to click on the x, y coords and it clicks way under the match? It clicks on the right x but way under the right y coord?

Comment: I'm not sure, but possibly you need to account for the offset created by the window bar at the top - depending on the implementation of your robot. If not, you can open a new question concerning the robot not clicking on specified coordinates.

Comment: thanks i found the solution, https://i.imgur.com/RcJXlia.jpg, i had this shit on 125% and now on 100% and works fine...